# Warning: validateDOMNesting: Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tr>. Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown, whitespace

I can't figure out where this whitespace is coming from. The data is coming as a table after being generated as markdown with the help of showdown and react-mde.

Relevant description : When the table icon of the editor is clicked, it generates a table markdown which is converted to html upon submission and then sent to the database. Upon retrieval, the raw html is sanitized against xxs attacks before being rendered.

- **TextArea component.**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMde from "react-mde";
import "react-mde/lib/styles/css/react-mde-all.css";
import "./Contributions.css";
import { TableIcon } from "./Icons";
import { useReducerProvider } from "./Context/BugPageContext";
import "./TextArea.scss";

export default function TextArea({
    context,
    converter,
    textAreaName,
    refElement,
    textAreaDescription,
    onChangeHandler,
    onBlurHandler
}) {
    const [{}, dispatch] = useReducerProvider();
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState("write");
    const tableCommand = {
        name: "my-custom-command",
        icon: () => (
            <span role="img" aria-label="nice">
                <TableIcon />
            </span>
        ),
        execute: opts => {
            opts.textApi.replaceSelection(
                '|                     |       col 1      |        col2      |\n' +
                '| ------------- |:-------------:|:-------------:|\n' +
                '|   **row 1**   |          -         |          -         |\n' +
                '|   **row 2**   |          -         |          -         |\n' +
                '|   **row 3**   |          -         |          -         |'
            );
        }
    };

    return (
        <div
            ref={refElement}
            className="w-full flex-col justify-center items-center"
        >
            <ReactMde
                name={textAreaName}
                classes={{
                    reactMde: "",
                    toolbar: "",
                    preview: "",
                    textArea: "form__focus",
                    suggestionsDropdown: ""
                }}
                // rows="5"
                commands={{
                    table: tableCommand
                }}
                toolbarCommands={[
                    ["header", "bold", "italic", "strikethrough"],
                    ["link", "quote", "code", "image"],
                    ["unordered-list", "ordered-list", "checked-list", "table"]
                ]}
                value={textAreaDescription}
                onChange={content => {
                    if (onChangeHandler) {
                        if (context == "AddBug") {
                            onChangeHandler("description", content);
                        } else {
                            onChangeHandler(content);
                        }
                    } else {
                        dispatch({
                            type: "ADD_TEXTAREA_CONTRIBUTION",
                            textareaContribution: content
                        });
                    }
                }}
                onBlur={onBlurHandler ? onBlurHandler : ""}
                selectedTab={selectedTab}
                onTabChange={setSelectedTab}
                generateMarkdownPreview={markdown =>
                    Promise.resolve(converter.makeHtml(markdown))
                }
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

- **Jsx**

```
<div className="contribution_content_wrapper mt-2 break-all ml-10 text-sm text-gray-300">
    {console.log( "contribution?.content", contribution?.content )}
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(contribution?.content) }} />
</div>
```

- **Output of the console log**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th style="text-align:center;">col 1</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>row 1</strong></td>
<td style="text-align:center;">-</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>row 2</strong></td>
<td style="text-align:center;">-</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>row 3</strong></td>
<td style="text-align:center;">-</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">-</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```